# Create array of 16 byte values with leading 0's and final byte being each hex value

Tags: arrays, c, byte

I am looking to make an array that contains 256 elements each element should be incremented hence. `array[0]` should be `00000000000000000000000000000000` and `array[1]` should be `00000000000000000000000000000001` all the way up to `array[255]` should be `000000000000000000000000000000FF`
Currently all I have is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char arr[16] = {[0 ... 15] = 0x00};
    memset(arr, 0x00, sizeof(arr));
    printf("%s\n",arr);
}
```

Which currently just prints a new line and that's all.
My goal is to have something similar to:

```
...
int main()
{
    unsigned char arr[256][16];
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
       memset(arr[i],0x00,sizeof(arr[i]));
       //Add code to create each 16 byte hex string
       printf("%s\n",arr[i]); //Print each 16 byte string to make sure they're correct
    }
}
```

Comment: `unsigned char arr[256][17]; ... snprintf(arr[i], sizeof arr[i], "%016x", i);` Notice 17 instead of 16 in order to null-terminate the array.

Comment: The *character* `'0'` is very different from the *integer* `0`. And remember that the `%s` format prints a null-terminated string, where the null-terminator is equal to the *integer* `0`.

Comment: If you want to dump an array of octets in hex-output form to a stream, you have to write the code to do it. There is no call-this-function provided to do it for you.  Notable, btw, the memset is unnecessary if you initialize `arr` properly in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

From the above comments, this worked:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char arr[256][33];
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
       snprintf(arr[i], sizeof arr[i], "%032x", i);
       printf("%s\n",arr[i]); //Print each 16 byte string to make sure they're correct
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `memset`